# CreateUserWizard: After registering, I'd like the user to be automatically logged on

Tags: asp.net, createuserwizard

I am using the `CreateUserWizard` to register a user. The control's built-in logic is doing all the work to add the user. However upon registering, I would like the user to be considered "authenticated." I thought that the `Authenticate` function would have authenticated me, but the function sets the `Authenticated` Boolean to False. Note however that the `ValidateUser` function returns True.

How do I automatically sign on/authenticate the use after registering so he doesn't have to "log on" after just registering with his new credentials?

```
Protected Sub CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(ByVal sender As Object, 
              ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CreateUserWizard1.CreatedUser

  Dim Authenticated As Boolean =
                     FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(CreateUserWizard1.UserName,
                                                      CreateUserWizard1.Password)
  Dim Validated As Boolean = Membership.ValidateUser(CreateUserWizard1.UserName,
                                                     CreateUserWizard1.Password) 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the validated does indeed turn out to be correct then you can use SetAuthCookie.